# Update number of unread messages in Firebase using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, chat

I am trying to implement chat in my app.
When a user sends a message to another user, I want to add 1 to a counter of "unread number of messages" saved in Firebase.

This is my Firebase tree:

[image: Firebase Tree]

The field "newMessage" is the counter for how many unread msgs I have.
After "Messages", there is the Contact ID (The one the msg is being sent to), then the Sender ID (The one that send a msg to this contact) and then "newMessage" is how many unread messages there are from Sender to Contact.

I have written this function to add a new unread msg:

```
private func AddNewMsgTick(contactID: String)
    {
        let ref = Constants.refs.databaseChats.child(contactID).child(senderId)

        ref.observe( .value, with: {(snapshot) in

            let dataDic = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

            if let currentNewMsgs = dataDic!["newMessage"] as? Int
            {
                let newIntMsg = currentNewMsgs + 1
                ref.setValue(newIntMsg) // This isn't right and should be updated
            }

        })
    }
```

And this code doesn't seem to work properly. I have tried a couple of iterations on it, using either `ref.observeSingleEvent`, and also tried using `.ChildAdd`, and now I have reached an iteration where I'm trying to cast the snapshot into a dictionary and getting the value from there.

All my function iterations failed. I am having trouble with properly reading the value and parsing it into Int. It reads wrong information, as can be seen here :

[image: Wrong information read]

The function that is activated once "Send" button is pressed in chat :

```
override func didPressSend(_ button: UIButton!, withMessageText text: String!, senderId: String!, senderDisplayName: String!, date: Date!)
    {
        Constants.refs.databaseChats.child(senderId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in

            if !snapshot.hasChild(self.contactID!)
            {
                self.CreateChatRoom(creatorID: senderId, creatorName: senderDisplayName, contactID: self.contactID!, contactName: self.contactDisplayName!)
            }

            let stringMsgPostedOn = Constants.GetCurrentDateTimeString()
            let senderRef = Constants.refs.databaseChats.child(senderId).child(self.contactID!).child("Messages").child(stringMsgPostedOn)
            let contactRef = Constants.refs.databaseChats.child(self.contactID!).child(senderId).child("Messages").child(stringMsgPostedOn)

            let senderRefLite = Constants.refs.databaseChatsLite.child(senderId).child(self.contactID!)
            let contactRefLite = Constants.refs.databaseChatsLite.child(self.contactID!).child(senderId)

            let message = ["userID": senderId, "userName": senderDisplayName, "text": text]
            let messageLite = ["userName": self.contactDisplayName, "lastMessage": text]

            // Make all this one transaction
            senderRef.setValue(message)
            senderRefLite.setValue(messageLite)

            contactRef.setValue(message)
            contactRefLite.setValue(messageLite)
            self.AddNewMsgTick(contactID: self.contactID!)
            self.finishSendingMessage()


        })


    }
```

Chat room initialization:

```
private func CreateChatRoom(creatorID: String, creatorName: String ,contactID: String, contactName: String)
    {
        let infoForCreator = ["userName": contactName, "newMessage" : String(0)]
        let infoForContact = ["userName": creatorName, "newMessage" : String(0)]



        let childUpdates = ["Messages/\(creatorID)/\(contactID)/": infoForCreator,
                            "Messages/\(contactID)/\(creatorID)/": infoForContact,
                            "ChatRoomsLite/\(creatorID)/\(contactID)/": infoForCreator,
                            "ChatRoomsLite/\(contactID)/\(creatorID)/": infoForContact
                            ]

        Constants.refs.databaseRoot.updateChildValues(childUpdates)
    }
```

What is the proper way of implementing this function ? Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In place of `.value` try using `.childChanged`, 
as per definition - for `.childChanged`  
A child node at a location changes.

Comment: But .childChanged fires up when a child is changed, and I want to change an existing one

Comment: Did you even try??? Because the documentation clearly tells https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data

Comment: I don't understand you. It clearly states it listens to changes, that is NOT what I want to do. I want to change it myself, not do something when it is changed.

Comment: And just to I can say so without hesitation - I just tried it, and it did not give me the values I need at all.

Comment: What does the *didPressSend* and *CreateChatRoom* functions have to do with incrementing a value in a Firebase node? It appears unrelated and should probably be removed to keep the question clear - if you are having issues with that code, post it in a separate question and we'll take a look!

Comment: In your Firebase structure, newMessage is being stored as a string of "0" (which isn't zero, it's a string) and if you want to store values, store them as Int's instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactor your CreateChatRoom func like this:

```
    let infoForCreator = ["userName": contactName, "newMessage" : 0]
    let infoForContact = ["userName": creatorName, "newMessage" : 0]
```

And, try to change your AddNewMsgTick to use:

```
ref.observeSingleEvent
```

Comment: Added to post :)

Comment: This is not an answer. It should be a comment.

Comment: sorry, will use comments further

Comment: I added to my post the function I initialize it to "0".

Comment: The answer you just gave is wrong as I ALWAYS want to update the amount of unread msgs to ++ and not set it to 0 here at all.

Comment: Yes. But you saving newMessage count as String, but trying to unwrap it as Int. Try my edited answer.

Comment: This seemed to work, until something weird happened. my "newMessage" count went up to about 100,000+. Is there a chance I have in my code some kind of an infinite loop in the "AddNewMsgTick" function ?

Comment: Yes, there seems to be some kind of infinite loop

Comment: in addNewMsgTick, try to use ..observeSingleEvent instead of .ovserve(value)

Comment: @Ofri Unfortunately this answer is sending you in the wrong direction and doesn't address the initial question which was *I want to add 1 to a counter of "unread number of messages" saved in Firebase.* If this answer is incorrect as you mention above, please don't accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest simplifying your code. The structure you have is fine and since you know the specific path to the data that needs to be updated, use it.

Assume a Firebase structure

```
messages
   contact_0
      sender_0
         messages
            ...
         newMessage: 0
      sender_1
         messages
            ..
         newMessage: 5
```

If we want to increment sender_0's messages counter, just access and update it at it's path like this:

```
let contactRef = self.ref.child("messages").child("contact_0")
let newMessagesRef = contactRef.child("sender_0").child("newMessage")
newMessagesRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    if let currentValue = snapshot.value as! Int? {
        let updatedValue = currentValue + 1
        ref.setValue(updatedValue)
    }
})
```

**Very important** to note that in your question, newMessage is being stored as a string of "0" (which isn't zero, it's a string) and if you want to store values, store them as Int's instead.